# Как сделать hover плавным, если включается класс?

Tags: css, scss

Знаю про свойство `transition`, но оно работает при таком коде:

```
a {
  transition:transform 0.1s;
  &:hover {
    transform:scale(1.1);
}
}
```

А у меня такой код:

```
a {
      transition:transform 0.1s;
      &:hover {
        .bigger{
           transform:scale(1.1);
           display: block;

    }
    }
}
```

И у меня не работает плавность. Как можно добавить плавности, если при ховере появляется блок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, если у вас css компилится через препроцессор, но хочу предупредить, что тэг A инлайновый и класть в него элемент с `display: block` опасно.

```
a {
  .bigger {
    transition: transform 0.1s;
  }
  &:hover {
    .bigger {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPD**. Как вариант можно попробовать использовать `position: absolute;` и `opacity`:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a .bigger {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}
a:hover .bigger {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  This is <span class="bigger">WOW!</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Нет, не заработало. Еще есть какие то идеи?

Comment: Идеи? После того, как я в ответе предоставил рабочий пример, остаётся только 2 идеи: либо у вас кривой код, либо у вашего кода кривой хозяин

Comment: В вашем коде обязателен positiion:absolute?

Comment: Извини, не туда transition сунул. Все таки, кривой хозяин)Спасибо